# Adding to the default upper limit of ylim()

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering if I can have R add a bit more (say by a factor of 1/3) to its default upper limit of `ylim = c(a, b)`  (here: `b + 1/3 * b`) when plotting anything?

Maybe you can show this in this R code:

```
plot(1:10, type="l", ann=FALSE)
```

or this:

```
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think so. Almost all of the details of graphical parameter settings in base graphics are documented in the `?par` page: in this case `yaxs` is the only relevant setting:

> ‘yaxs’ The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the
>             y-axis.  See ‘xaxs’ above.

and:

> ‘xaxs’ The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis.  Possible values are ‘"r"’, ‘"i"’, ‘"e"’, ‘"s"’, ‘"d"’.  The styles are generally controlled by the range of data or ‘xlim’, if given. ...
>   Style ‘"r"’ (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.

The 4 percent value is hard-coded [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a4bd1b6c67b252bcdec4b7ec41119d9581d8b3e/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L1968):

```
case 'r':
   temp = 0.04 * (max-min);
   min -= temp;
   max += temp;
break;
```

You could use `ggplot2` or `lattice` plots (which allow more customization) or write your own wrapper to modify the limits ...

Comment: I don't see how that would work without finding the maximum of the data yourself, in which case you might as well use `ylim` directly ... ?